# ASP.NET MVC - One style is applied, another is not

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am at my wits end here, using ASP.NET MVC5 with just the default project setting.

I changed the shared Layout page a bit, copied that from another project. The according css I put in the Site.css thinking that it'd be loaded automatically using the Scripts.Render as it is in the bundle, same as bootstrap.

Now to my surprise, the css is not loaded even though this

```
 <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is in the pages head. Bootstrap however is applied correctly (progressbar and buttons work properly).

What I have tried so far:

- Putting the Site.css in another folder
- Linking directly to the site css using `<link href...`
- Creating a new project and performing the same steps
- Creating an exception to the Content folder  in the web.config (read that somewhere, just tried it in hope it'd change something)

Now I created a JsFiddle to check it and it doesnt work there either.

https://jsfiddle.net/df5tw8qd/2

I'm sure it is a very small problem but I've been sitting here for 2 hours trying to fix it without any success, I just cant wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong. Probably doesnt help that I havent done any websites in years either.

The exact same combination of HTML/CSS works in my other ASP.NET mvc project

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just add the CSS file in **App_Start > BundleConfig.cs** like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Then, in your Layout, add this to the `<head>`:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: This is how it was at the beginning but it didnt work so I changed it. It seems like the CSS is being loaded just not being applied. Or maybe theres just something completely wrong with my CSS seeing as even JsFiddle wont show it properly

Comment: If you View Source on the page, can you see the CSS file getting loaded?  If so, there may be style conflicts due to CSS specificity.

Comment: Yes, I can see it being referenced properly. I've ran it through a few syntax checkers but they all didnt show any errors. I'm not too sure about style conflicts, dont have that much CSS experience but I'll make sure to look that up.

Comment: For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity